# Is there a way to see sub-tasks in the “Today”-view of Reminders on iOS?

Tags: ios, reminders

I have a reminder with sub-reminders set. When looking at it in “Today” I just see this:

[image]

The only way to see the sub-reminders are to click “Details”. There’s no way I’ve found to expand them in place in the list. **Is that possible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the sub-reminders are not displayed is that date settings for reminders are not recursive. That is: setting a date for a reminder doesn’t affect its children. In the example in the question only the parent reminder has a set date. The children will not be displayed since they don’t inherit the expiry date from their parent.

If you want children to be visible, they have to have a set expiry date too.